# How to get the number of elements of a C-array like this?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a C-array like this:

```
double arr[] = {
    0.0,    0.1, 0.2, 0.5,
    0.1,    0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
    0.2,    0.0, 0.1, 0.3
};
```

Is it safe to get the number of elements like this?

```
int numElements = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Remember this will not work for dynamic arrays, I also [explain how  `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` works/meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009725/weird-behavior-when-printing-array-in-c/18009736#18009736)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a safe way and if you'll look at other question about size of array you'll find this as one of the most common suggestions

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413046/how-to-get-the-length-of-array-in-c-is-sizeof-is-one-of-the-solution)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162923/calculate-length-of-array-in-c-by-using-function)

and so on.

actually in the last one the suggestion is to do

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE( array ) sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] )
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the best way. Even it is suggested in `C programming` book by `Dennis ritchie`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any other way to do this, since you don't have a size.

It is [reliable, yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fa73784b248a5015e90d5deff5c65ff0-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Answer (score 2):

There are no other better way according to my knowledge, there are no problem in this one.
In `java`, there are jagged arrays. If it's also in `c`, then your thought may be correct.