# Using qsort in C on an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

I can't figure out how to use qsort. I want to sort an array of strings. Like so:

```
John              Adam
Adam      ->      John
Stacy             Stacy
```

However, nothing I do seems to work. I've tried copying exactly what others have used (about 5 different qsort functions from various sources) and nothing has worked. I have one for int's that works (backwards but at least it works).

Here's the necessary code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
char name[80];
int age;
} RECORD;
RECORD record[25];

int main (int argc, char *argv[80]){     // Using command line to get my strings

    int i = 2, j;
    for(j = 0; j < (argc / 2); j++)      //Converting and storing my ages
    {
        record[j].age = atoi(argv[i]);
        i = i + 2;
    }

    int p, q = 1;
    for(p = 0; p < (argc / 2); p++)
    {
        strcpy(record[p].name, argv[q]);
        q = q + 2;
    }
}

int compareByName(const void* a, const void* b) //The qsort that doesn't work at all
{
    const char *ia = (const char *)a;
    const char *ib = (const char *)b;

    return strncmp(ia, ib, 25);
}

int compareByAge (const void * a, const void * b)  //My other qsort that works backwards
{

    RECORD *RECORDA = (RECORD *)a;
    RECORD *RECORDB = (RECORD *)b;

    return ( RECORDB->age - RECORDA->age );
}

void printRecords(RECORD r[], int num){
//printing stuff here

double size = sizeof r[0];
double count = sizeof(r)/size;          //My qsort with size stuff, doesn't work
qsort(r, count, size, compareByName);   // if I do it the same as the other  

qsort (r, 25, sizeof(RECORD), compareByAge);   //My other qsort that works backwards

//more printing stuff here
}
```

Comment: Not that ages are likely to overflow, but to avoid overflow use `(RECORDB->age > RECORDA->age) - (RECORDB->age < RECORDA->age)`

Answer (score 4):

You don't have an array of strings, you have an array of `RECORD`s, and it sounds like you want to sort that array based on the strings in the `name` array of the records.  So you want something like:

```
int compareByName(const void *a_, const void *b_) {
    RECORD *a = a_, *b = b_;

    return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}
```

and then you sort with

```
qsort (r, 25, sizeof(RECORD), compareByName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see several issues here.

It's worth noting that `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, so you can't use `sizeof(r)` to determine the size of a dynamically-sized array you were passed.  I'm going to guess that's why `num` is passed in to `printRecords`.

As @Chris points out, you're sorting `RECORD` structures rather than character pointers, so the comparison function and the `qsort` call both need to take that into account.

You have the subtraction reversed in the age comparison - it needs to return a negative number if the left side is less than the right side, so use `RECORDA->age - RECORDB->age`.

Answer (score 1):

First off (this is why your strings aren't sorting), `double count = sizeof(r)/size;` is wrong.  sizeof(r) isn't doing what you expect it to.  You'll need to pass the size of the array to printRecords() as described in this question:

[How to get the length of array in C? is "sizeof" is one of the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413046/how-to-get-the-length-of-array-in-c-is-sizeof-is-one-of-the-solution)

Second off, 
`int compareByAge (const void * a, const void * b)  //My other qsort that works backwards` is backwards because you're doing it backwards.  Comparator functions always return A - B, not B - A.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the sizeof problem. When I replace `RECORDB->age - RECORDA->age` with `RECORDA->age - RECORDB->age`, the qsort stops working at all and gives me blank data for my print function. Same thing with my now working name qsort. If I try to flip them the right way they give blank data.