# What's the correct way to use scanf_s in using string arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

```c
char array1[10];
scanf_s("%9s", array1, (unsigned)_countof(array1);
```

What's mean of `(unsigned)_countof(array1)`?

and what's different from use `scanf_s("%9s", array1, sizeof(array1);`?

both worked, but I want to understand about it more surely

Comment: Let me guess that `_countof()`is a macro that returns the number of elements in an array. I think MSVC defines this, but it is not part of any ANSI or POSIX standard AFAIK.

Comment: Add a ending bracket in your 2nd line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the correct way to use `scanf_s` in using string arrays?

`scanf_s()` with `"%9s"` is not for *string arrays*.  It is for reading text and saving as a single *string*, which is a *character array* with a *null character*.

Its proper use is complicated by MSVC expects a different type in the count argument than C11.  In C11 and later, `scanf_s()` is an optional function of the standard library and lacks wide acceptance.

```
// MSVC - type unsigned expected, hence the cast.
scanf_s("%9s", array1, (unsigned)_countof(array1);

// C11 - type size_t expected
scanf_s("%9s", array1, sizeof array1 / sizeof array1[0]);
```

Proper use of either obliges code to check the return value of `scanf_s()`

```
if (1 == scanf_s("%9s", ...)) Success();
else Fail();
```

---

> What's mean of `(unsigned)_countof(array1)`?

`_countof()` is an MSVC macro equivalent to [`(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro?view=msvc-170).  When passed an array, it returns the count of elements in the array as type `size_t`.  Casting to `unsigned` gets the expected type as with MSVC `scanf_s()`.  The value may truncate due to the cast - a rare issue with huge arrays.

---

> what's different from use `scanf_s("%9s", array1, sizeof(array1));`?

The expected type of `sizeof(array1)` is `size_t` and not `unsigned` as expected in MSVC - leading to *undefined behavior*.  When `size_t` is as `unsigned`, that is OK, else a real problem.

The conceptual value is wrong.  It should be the array element **count**, not the byte **size** of the array.  Either OK here as `sizeof(char)==1`, yet wrong if code moved to say using wide characters.

---

> both worked

Code is not portable.  It may have "worked" in OP's case, but lacks portability.

---

Consider alternatives to `scanf_s(), scanf()` like `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` and `_countof` are different.
(edit:) In this case you should use `countof`.

[`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) is an operator in C that returns the **memory size** occupied by a variable, in bytes.
In this case, `array1` is an array of 10 chars, so it's size is ten times the size of a `char`, and `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte. So the value of `sizeof(array1)` is 10 * 1 = 10 bytes.

Note that in C you can use `sizeof` on any variable (e.g. `sizeof(array1)`) or on any type (e.g. `sizeof(int)`).

[`_countof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro?view=msvc-170) is a macro (only available on Microsoft platforms) that gives you the **number of elements** declared in an array variable. In this case your `array1` variable has 10 elements, so `_countof(array1)` will be 10.

Now *in your precise case* this happens to be the same result because the size of each `char` is 1, but this wouldn't be the same if, for example, your variable was an array of `int`s.

```
int array2[10];

sizeof(array2);  // = 40 
_countof(array2); // = 10
```

An `int` is (usually) 4 bytes, so an array of 10 `int`s will have a size of 10*4 = 40 bytes. On the other hand, `_countof` will just count how many elements are declared in the array, and still return 10.

In fact, we can see that the definition of `_countof` is litterally `sizeof(array)` divided by `sizeof(array[0])`, that is, the size of an individual element.

Since `scanf_s` with `"%s"` expects a number of items, you should be using `_countof`. (edit).

You might also want to be careful with `sizeof` (and `_countof`) on arrays, and avoid using them on pointers. Also be aware that `_countof` will not work outside of Visual Studio. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413046/how-to-get-the-length-of-an-array-in-c-is-sizeof-a-solution?noredirect=1&lq=1) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415530/equivalents-to-msvcs-countof-in-other-compilers).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you're right. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Louen: you should also expand on the types of `sizeof(array)` and `_countof(array)`, which are `size_t` as expected by `scanf_s` as defined in the C Standard as an optional feature. Yet the Microsoft version of the same function expects a value of type `UNSIGNED` for the size argument that follows the pointer. This explains the cast to `(unsigned)` in the posted code. This inconsistency between Microsoft's and the standard version of the `scanf_s` and the fact that it is optional function are good reasons to avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is compiler based, `GCC 11.1.0 on Arch Linux` does not have functions like `scanf_s` and `_countof`. These functions/macros might be valid in Windows.

I read some docs on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170). So, `_countof` is a macro which calls `sizeof()` internally and `scanf_s` is similar to `scanf` in standard C17.

> What's mean of (unsigned)_countof(array1)? and what's different from use scanf_s("%9s", array1, sizeof(array1);? both work, but I want to understand about it more surely

Here the macro `_countof` is counting the length of the [stack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/) stored array, which in this case is `10`.

`_countof` macro expands to:

```
#define _countof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
// the operation goes for `array1` like this:
// 10 * 1 byte / 1 byte
// 1 byte is the sizeof char
// hence, 10 is returned as the result of the above operation
```

And `(unsigned)` is just type casting the value of the above operation.

NOTE: As `_countof` is calling `sizeof()` do not use this inside a function the get the length of an array. Because sizeof(arr_ptr) will return the size of pointer which is *8 bytes in my case (x86_64 architecture)*.

Conclusion:

There no `_countof` is just calling `sizeof()`. I would like to suggest you to use `sizeof` and `scanf` functions because they are cross-platform and portable throughout the C standards.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation !

Comment: Glad you liked it

Comment: Note that if `_countof` is defined as you wrote, the cast `(unsigned)_countof(array1)` would only apply to the first operand `sizeof(array)` and the resulting type might still be larger than `unsigned`. The definition is probably parenthesized as `#define _countof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))`

Comment: On the contrary, the type matters as the value is passed to a vararg function. `sizeof()` and `_countof()` both are 64-bit values whereas casting to `(unsigned)` converts the value to a 32-bit one. I commented on *Louen*'s answer about the inconsistency in `scanf_s` leading to the need for a cast in MSVC.

Comment: @chqrlie Now you can typecast it using `(unsigned)` and the whole result will be typecasted

Comment: Yes, as expected by any programmer reading `(unsigned)_countof(array1)`.  It is very important to always parenthesize macro expansions properly and defensively.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks for your time to improve my answer