# Why does my array not have the right length after initializing it?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to initialize an array of variable length with random zeros and ones. My problem is that the array I created seems to only have a length of 4 elements.
Why is that?

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int length = 20;
    int *array = (int *) calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = 1;
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < sizeof(array); j++) {
        printf("%d", array[j]);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a C-Array have a wrong sizeof() value when it's passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950332/why-does-a-c-array-have-a-wrong-sizeof-value-when-its-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is, instead of the the sizeof operator in `for (j = 0; j < sizeof(array); j++)`, use `for (j = 0; j < length; j++)`.

Also, i presume you want 20 elements of 0s and 1s in the array. So you might want to change

in the line `for (i = 1; i < length; i++)`

use for `(i = 0; i < length; i++)` instead.

Now for the explanation, the primary bug in the code is in the line

for (j = 0; j < sizeof(array); j++)

The **sizeof** operator returns size in bytes of the object representation of type. In your case the type is **int**, hence for a **32 bit** machine, the **sizeof operator will return 4** and for a **64 bit machine it will return 8.** So in the second loop, runtime length is returned as 4(your machine is 32bit).

To explore all the elements you have input in the first loop, just use the same **length** variable to point to each index of the array instead of the **sizeof** operator.

Comment: Thanks! So how exactly do I know whether the name of my array represents the array itself or just a pointer to its first element?

Comment: you are allocating memory for an array and assigning a pointer to it. The pointer would always point to the address of the first index and then increment as you iterate over it. And this is generic for arrays declared with definite size as well.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `array` is `int *`, so the size of `array` in the sense of `sizeof(array)` is the size of a pointer value (i.e. 4 on 32 bit systems and 8 on 64 bit systems).

You should simply write `for (j = 0; j < length; j++)` instead of `for (j = 0; j < sizeof(array); j++)`.

Answer (score 3):

You issue is that `sizeof(array)` returns you the size of `int *`, which on your systems evaluates to 4. Simply use `j < length` as stop criterion in the second iteration.